# Real analysis problem in Royden's book

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

There is one problem in the Royden's book that I'm confused (for now)

**Problem.** If $E$ has finite (Lebesgue) outer measure. Show that $\exists F_\sigma=F,\exists G_\delta=G$ for which $F\subseteq E\subseteq G$ and $\lambda^o(F)=\lambda^o(E)=\lambda^o(G).$

Here $\lambda^o(A)$ means the outer measure of $A$ and $F_\sigma, G_\delta$ means countable union of closed sets and countable intersections of open sets, respectively. Here is my proof.

Let $\mathcal O_k\supseteq E$ be open set such that $\lambda^o(\mathcal O_k)<\lambda^o(E)+\frac{1}{k}$ by the definition of outer measure (which is $\lambda^o(A)=\inf\left\{\lambda(\mathcal O):\mathcal O^{op}\supseteq A\right\}$ and $\lambda(\mathcal O)$ is the sum of the length of the disjoint unions of open intervals in $\mathbb R$.)

I am confused here since it seems to me that we can extend the result to $\lambda^o(E)=\infty$ while the inequality changes by adding equality (is this correct? and I think if it's so why the problem does state the finite outer measure). Then, we do the steps such as let $G=\bigcap_{k\ge 1} \mathcal O_k$ so that $E\subseteq G$ and
$$\lambda^o(E)\le \lambda^o(G)\le \lambda^o(\mathcal O_k)\le \lambda^o(E)+\dfrac{1}{k},$$
and $k$ is independent so we have $\lambda^o(E)=\lambda(G) \blacksquare$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case $\lambda^o(E) = \infty$ this part of the question is trivial: you just want $E \subseteq G$ where $G$ is a $G_\delta$ with $\lambda^o(G) = \infty$.  Well, you might as well take $G = \mathbb R$.

The other part, with $F_\sigma$ set $F \subseteq E$, is **not** true.  A Bernstein set has nonzero outer measure but contains no $F_\sigma$ of positive measure, in fact contain no uncountable closed set.

Comment: Do you mean when $\lambda^o(E)=\infty$ for such Bernstein set or just positive outer measure? Since the problem required to prove for finite case.

Comment: A Bernstein set in $\mathbb R$ has outer measure $\infty$.  Its intersection with an interval has outer measure the length of the interval.